# App crashes on dismissViewControllerAnimated:

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have a regular view controller that attempts to present a controller via **presentViewController** or by pushing the controller using the UINavigationController.

When I call the **dismissViewControllerAnimated:** method or click the back button when it's pushed via the UINavigationController, the app will crash with the following errors:

```
012-12-01 13:09:15.789 stats[12370:c07] *** Assertion failure in -[NSLayoutConstraint constant], /SourceCache/Foundation_Sim/Foundation-992/Layout.subproj/NSLayoutConstraint.m:560
2012-12-01 13:09:15.790 stats[12370:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '(null)'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x4ac012 0x1974e7e 0x4abe78 0x140af35 0x15253a2 0x1527cda 0x15274f1 0xdf4bbe 0xdf4da7 0x908be4 0x90905d 0x90905d 0x90905d 0x90905d 0x90905d 0x90905d 0x90905d 0x90905d 0x90905d 0x9045e6 0x90aaf4 0x902eed 0x97cad6 0xba9f44 0xba94eb 0x9a7a11 0x9a6ecd 0x9a6ecd 0x9a7bdb 0xa72739d 0x2e7b0 0xd71b5 0xd6f38 0xd8a19 0x4a01bd 0x4a00d6 0x4a024a 0xe27d69 0xe2913e 0x49bcf9 0x49b94e 0x4a01bd 0x4a00d6 0x4a024a 0xe27d69 0xe279da 0x49bcf9 0x49b94e 0x4a01bd 0x4a00d6 0x4a024a 0xe27d69 0xddb0a7 0x49bcf9 0x49b94e 0x4a01bd 0x4a00d6 0x4a024a 0xe27d69 0xe010cf 0x514753f 0x5159014 0x51497d5 0x452af5 0x451f44 0x451e1b 0x240c7e3 0x240c668 0x8bc65c 0x1e34d 0x2215)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

This happens on both, the simulator and on the device.

Here's how I'm presenting the controller:

**UINavigationController**

```
ChartViewController *chartViewer = [[ChartViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChartViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:chartViewer animated:YES];
```

**presentViewController:**

```
ChartViewController *chartViewer = [[ChartViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChartViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self presentViewController:chartViewer animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Did you check if the chartViewer object gets created or not?
In the first case, do you have a navigationController in your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably caused by the Auto Layout feature on the new XCode.

Check in your XIB if the Use AutoLayout feature is enabled. If it is, disable and try it again:
[image]

Comment: Not helpful if you're utilizing auto-layout

Comment: Agree, but in this specific scenario, the Auto Layout is what is causing the crash and apparently, the user is not using Auto Layout.